# How to add record in AWS Route 53 that redirects to 3rd party cloud page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a Hosted zone in AWS Route 53 & using it to host my site with S3.
However, I want to add a subdomain that will redirect to a shared page from other cloud providers like Dropbox or Azure.

What I have been trying -

1. I have a simple file/ pic in a publicly shared folder. I create a shared link from it
2. In my route 53 i create a new record with CNAME type & insert the generated link
3. When i hit the created record in browser, i get error -

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

My Record details are -

[image: Route 53 record]

Is it possible to create a record for my usecase using Route 53? If yes, am i missing any steps?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this with Route53 or DNS. DNS cannot handle HTTP paths and can only resolve domain names to IP addresses (or another domain in the case of CNAME records). So while a CNAME record can redirect to another domain name, it cannot redirect to a specific path on that domain.

You might look into setting up a URL redirect in your webapp or some sort of proxy for this instead.

Comment: Thought the same for paths as most of the records in route 53 did not contain path '/' in values. 
For URL redirection, can you share more info? As my main purpose is users can use simple domain name to access shared folders rather than long randomly shared folder urls.

Comment: Since the site is hosted in s3, the easiest way could be routing rules -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects